# Android - deleted my database manually, app won't start anymore?

Tags: android, sqlite

I deleted my database file manually (using `*adb shell* and sqlite3`).

Ever since then, my app doesn't recreates the database file (and throws an exception upon starting). I'm using `ORMLite`.

I tried wiping the data before starting the emulator ("`Wipe data`"). But it didn't help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: force stop your application then run your app.. this time your app will create database file

Comment: It didn't help. Maybe the problem isn't what I think.

Comment: Can u share the exception?

Comment: Did you try debugging step by step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I inspected the problem and saw this:

> 01-09 06:09:38.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1228):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.fileexplorermanager/com.landa.fileexplorermanager.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must specify one of id,
>   generatedId, and generatedIdSequence with id

It appears the problem was this:

```
...
@DatabaseField(id = true, generatedId = true, allowGeneratedIdInsert=true)
private Integer id;
...
```

I misinterpreted the way DatabaseField attributes work ( I specified three, instead of only one).

Comment: Saved my life. I had a sub-object with 2 of those.. and the error was point to the parent object.. took some time to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With the emulator running, navigate to Settings -> Apps, select your app an press the "Clear data" button.

You can also try to uninstall and then reinstall the application.